# Image ghost effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

Do anyone know how this effect is done (library, javascript, etc)? I never saw this and I'm looking for the name.

When you scroll the images get a ghost effect and seem to drag it until you stop.

This [website](https://yelvy.com/) has the effect I'm looking for (product images), if you scroll down.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like parallax

Comment: You can copy from their site: [link](https://yelvy.com/app/themes/yelvy/assets/bin/vendors/vendors.min.js)

Comment: @DomenikReitzner I'm not sure promoting potential copyright infringement is considered best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website example you gave is using a Javascript library called TweenMax, by GreenStock (https://greensock.com/tweenmax).

Whilst GreenStock do provide plugins and examples (premium and free), you may find that you need to familiarise yourself with TweenMax' documentation, so you can build this yourself.

You can get started fairly quickly by following their video tutorials https://greensock.com/video-training